# API for Get venues for nearrby Location in foursquare

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, foursquare

1)I want to fetch the venues for the nearby location by passing the latitude and longitude of to the API in foursquare.
I got this url:-[this](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=23.3456,72.4346&oauth_token=Q5PMJCAEZXD04H1SCOUTB0KJT0W3D0C3ADP32SSUVDNVXSMK&v=20121121)and i got peroper response.

But for this latitude and longitude:- 32.3456,141.4346
([url](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=32.3456,141.4346&oauth_token=Q5PMJCAEZXD04H1SCOUTB0KJT0W3D0C3ADP32SSUVDNVXSMK&v=20121121))
I did not get any data.

Same for Facebook.I use this :- [facebook API](https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=hotel&type=place&center=23.20,72.427&distance=50000&access_token=392518770824937%7C0378j76S-ye24_USAZZ0VibqTbA)

But i want the list of generalized category listing from this API.And this API only gives me data of hotels only.Because i pass q=hotel.

2)How to get oauth_token for foursquare?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you did not get any data for that location is because there are no venues in that area. If you follow this [link](https://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&client=safari&q=-32.3456,141.4346%20maps&ie=UTF-8&ei=fqSuUNKfLdHW0gHU04D4Dg&ved=0CAoQ_AUoAA#bmb=1) you will see that location is in a remote area of Australia.

For help with connecting users to Foursquare, you can use these [instructions](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth)